# addGrowConstant ArrayList?

Tags: arrays, arraylist, addition, singly-linked-list

So I keep getting OutOfBoundsExceptions from my code because the initial capacity (2) is too low. The Growth Constant is 10. What is there to do to fix this problem

```
public void addGrowConstant(int i, E e) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {  
//TODO Complete ArrayList addGrowConstant method  
  while(size<=GROWTH_CONSTANT){  
      resize(1);  
      data[i+1]=data[i];  
      data[i]=e;  
      size++;  
  }
```

}